# Position vector about skiing

Tags: vectors

I have a question about position vectors, I have looked everywhere I can find to get information on it. It is in a form I cannot see used anywhere else.

A ski jumper starts h metres above the jump, and skies down a slope towards it. Once he reaches the jump he takes off into the air. Once she has jumped, she has a position vector

$$\boldsymbol {r}(t) = \sqrt{10h} \,t \, \boldsymbol {i}+ t(\sqrt{10h}- 5mt) \boldsymbol {j}$$

$m$ is his mass in kg. After jumping, he will eventually land on the ground, which is 1 metre below the jump. Using the position vector, find the ski jumpers height above the jump in terms of $m$, $h$ and his horizontal distance without time. The answer should not have any square roots.

If anyone can give me the slightest nudge in the right direction it would be great, been stuck on this for hours and still cannot figure out where to start.

Comment: After the jump you must considerazione the effect of gravity

Comment: @N74 It’s already in there. The $10$ is clearly $g$ in mks units rounded to the nearest integer, and the $5$ is half that.

Comment: @amd you're right, I got confused by the $mt$ notation. Still it is not clear why the OP multiplies $g$ by $m$: gravity is independent by the mass.

Comment: @N74 The presence of the $m$ is indeed puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Find the time $t$ that it takes to travel some horizontal distance $x$—this is the coefficient of $\mathbf i$—and substitute that into the expression for height.

Comment: There are no given units or values for any of the coefficients. Unless I am missing something really obvious (been working on this stuff all night, good chance I am now), I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Looks like Jens got you sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to change the equation from a position vector depending on time, to an equation where the height (call it $y$) depends on the horizontal distance (call it $x$). Well, the horizontal distance is the coefficient of $i$ and the height is the coefficient of $j$. That is: $$x = \sqrt{10h}t$$ $$y = t(\sqrt{10h}- 5mt)$$

Now find $t$ as a function of $x$ (using my first equation above) and substitute $t$ into the equation for $y$. You should then get $$y = x(1 - \frac{m}{2h}x)$$

Comment: I am stuck on the substituting t into the equation for y now. Is last formula the answer you got for that?

I think I have done something rather wrong as my answer is 

y = (x (sqrt(10) sqrt(h)-5 m(x/(sqrt(10) sqrt(h)))))/(sqrt(10) sqrt(h))

Comment: The last formula is the answer, yes. Your formula looks right, though its hard to tell when you don't use MathJax. Just simplify it. Multiply the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10h}}$ into the parentheses.

Comment: Ah I see. Think I have it now. Thank you very much. Sorry for not using the MathJax formatting, first time on the site.

Really, big big thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help. :)